# expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I'm trying to write the unit test for the Controller which is written in NEST.JS
Following is the login method for which Unit test is failing

```
@Post('login')
async login(@Body() payload: LoginPayload): Promise<any> {
    this.logger.info("Calling Loging");
    this.logger.debug("Calling Loging");
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(payload);
    return await this.authService.createToken(user);
}
```

Unit Test for the above code is written in the JEST framework.

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    // createInputDetails() Functions initializes the LoginPayload, RegisterPayload and User Object
    createInputDetails();
    module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [AuthController],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: AuthService,
          useFactory: () => ({
            createToken: jest.fn(() => true),
            validateUser: jest.fn(() => true),
          }),
        },
        {
          provide: UserService,
          useFactory: () => ({
            get: jest.fn(() => true),
            getByEmail: jest.fn(() => true),
            getByEmailAndPass: jest.fn(() => true),
            create: jest.fn(() => true),
          }),
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    controller = module.get<AuthController>(AuthController);
    authService = module.get<AuthService>(AuthService);
    userService = module.get<UserService>(UserService);
  });

  describe('login', () => {
    it('should validate user', async () => {
      controller.login(loginPayload);
      expect(authService.validateUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith(loginPayload);
      expect(authService.createToken).toHaveBeenCalledWith(user);
    })
  })
```

And I'm getting the following error. Need to know what I'm missing here?

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)
    Expected: {"email": "abc@xyz.com", "firstName": "abc", "lastName": "pqr", "password": "Test@1234", "profile": {"age": 32, "nickname": "abc"}, "userId": 14}

    Number of calls: 0

       96 |       controller.register(registerPayload);
       97 |       // expect(userService.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith(registerPayload);
    >  98 |       expect(authService.createToken).toHaveBeenCalledWith(user);
          |                                       ^
       99 |     })
      100 |   })
      101 | 

      at Object.it (modules/auth/auth.controller.spec.ts:98:39)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `controller.login` method is asynchronous, so you should be `await controller.login(registerPayload)` instead of calling it directly. I have a feeling that you jest is not waiting for the `nextTick` to process and is moving on without letting the controller method run its segment

Comment: "So it should be `await controller.login(registerPayload)`" - quote from my comment. Asynchronous methods must be awaited. Simple as that.

Comment: Well, i did it like that, it didn't work, it is very weird.